# TensorDot and axis reduction

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I have 2 tensors a and b like `[?,200,200,48]` and I would like to get the dot product on axis 4 to obtain a tensor like `[?,200,200,1]`.

I tried to use `tf.tensordot(a,b,axis=[[3][3]])` and the result is tensor like `[?,200,200,?,200,200]`

Where i'm bad?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

BS = 100
x = K.random_normal((BS, 200, 200, 48))
y = K.random_normal((BS, 200, 200, 48))

K.sum(tf.multiply(x, y[:tf.newaxis]), axis=-1, keepdims=True).shape
```

Detailed explanation from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657476/keras-dot-dot-layer-behavior-on-3d-tensors

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly!